# Aggregate - processing data from two columns in FUN

Tags: r

Many similar questions have been asked on this, but I couldn't find this concept elsewhere. Sorry if this is a repetition.

I'm wanting to aggregate over one column of a data frame and create a new column that is based on two old ones.

This is (non working) example code to show kind of what I'm attempting:

```
x <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
y <- c(1,2,3,4)
z <- c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)

myfun <- function (vec) {
  sum(vec['y']*vec['z']) / sum(vec['y'])
}

df_agg <- aggregate(cbind(df$y, df$z), list(df$x), myfun)
```

The outcome I'm expecting is:

```
Group.1   V1
a         (1*0.3+2*0.4)/3
b         (3*0.5+4*0.6)/7
```

Can this be achieved with aggregate? Or should I use some other function?

Answer (score 1):

For calculations involving multiple columns by group, we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'x' get the `sum` of product of 'y' and 'z' divided by the `sum` of 'y'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , .(Out = sum(y*z)/sum(y)) , by = x]
```

---

Or can be done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   summarise(Out = sum(y*z)/sum(y))
```

---

Or with `by` from `base R`

```
by(df[2:3], df[1], FUN = function(x) sum(x[1]*x[2])/sum(x[1]))
```

Comment: was writing a same time

Comment: @Bulat No problem, I thought so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, sum(y*z)/sum(y), by=x]
```

It gives:

```
   x        V1
1: a 0.3666667
2: b 0.5571429
```

Which is your desired output.

```
(1*0.3 + 2*0.4)/3 = 1.1/3 = 0.37
(3*0.5 + 4*0.6)/7 = 3.9/7 = 0.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are several one-liners that use no packages.  (1) and (1a) use `aggregate`.

**1) aggregate** Aggregate over the row indexes like this:

```
aggregate(list(V1 = 1:nrow(df)), df["x"], function(i) with(df[i, ], sum(y * z) / sum(y)))
```

giving:

```
  x        V1
1 a 0.3666667
2 b 0.5571429
```

which can be written in terms of the `myfun` defined in the question as follows:

```
aggregate(list(V1 = 1:nrow(df)), df["x"], function(i) myfun(df[i, ]))
```

**1a) aggregate(..., sum)**  Use aggregate to compute the sums of y and y*z and then divide in a second step:

```
with(aggregate(. ~ x, transform(df, yz = y*z), sum), data.frame(x, V1 = yz / y))
```

giving:

```
  x        V1
1 a 0.3666667
2 b 0.5571429
```

**2) by** or use `by`:

```
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$x, with, data.frame(x = x[1], V1 = sum(y * z) / sum(y))))
```

giving:

```
  x        V1
a a 0.3666667
b b 0.5571429
```

**3) tapply** One could also use a ratio of tapply calls although the form of output would be different:

```
with(df, tapply(y * z, x, sum) / tapply(y, x, sum))
```

giving:

```
        a         b 
0.3666667 0.5571429
```

To massage that into the required form:

```
setNames(as.data.frame.table(with(df, tapply(y * z, x, sum) / tapply(y, x, sum))), 
  c("x", "V1"))
```

**4) rowsum** rowsum can be used in a similar way to tapply. It also gives a different form of output as a one column matrix with the x values becoming row names:

```
m <- with(df, rowsum(y * z, x) / rowsum(y, x))
```

giving:

```
> m
       [,1]
a 0.3666667
b 0.5571429
```

We can put it in the required form like this:

```
data.frame(x = rownames(m), V1 = m)
```

**sqldf**

and here is an sqldf solution.  It does use the sqldf package but seems particularly straight-forward:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select x, sum(y * z) / sum(y) V1 from df group by x")
```

giving:

```
  x        V1
1 a 0.3666667
2 b 0.5571429
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in base R but requires rethinking things a bit more R-like. Note that in the aggregate help it uses cbind in aggregate but look at the functions receiving the new mini-data.frames. They only take one vector. The help examples show you that aggregate doesn't work how you were hoping here. Further, You should be taking advantage of vectorized math functions as much as possible. The following is the efficient base R way to do it and similar to answer 1a by @G. Grothendieck.

```
# make your data.frame
x <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
y <- c(1,2,3,4)
z <- c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z)

df$yz <- df$y * df$z #vectorize this step

# at this point you can use a cbind in aggregate if you wish but 
# it won't do the whole thing for you. This only leaves one highly 
# optimized mathematical function that isn't vectorized (sum)
tdf <- aggregate(cbind(y, yz) ~ x, data = df, sum)

tdf$myFunValue <- tdf$yz / tdf$y # final step vectorized
```

Try to get in the habit of thinking about R commands this way, with the bare minimum requiring an aggregate or apply family command and not doing traditional programming things like putting everything in one loop.